# Наполняем массив случайными парными числами до 8

Tags: javascript, массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как наполнить его именно парными числами ?у меня наполняется от 1 до 8, а нужно чтобы каждое число было парными, то есть 1,1,2,2,3,3... и так далее

```js
(()=>{
  const randomNumbers = []
  
  function shuffle(array) {
    let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;
  
    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
  
      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;
  
      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
   return array;
  }
  for (let i = 1; i <=8; i++)
  randomNumbers.push(i);
  shuffle(randomNumbers);
  console.log(randomNumbers);
})();
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замени

```
for (let i = 1; i <=8; i++)
    randomNumbers.push(i);
```

на

```
for (let i = 1; i <=8; i+=2) {
    randomNumbers.push(i);
    randomNumbers.push(i);
}
```

---

```js
(()=>{
  const randomNumbers = []
  
  function shuffle(array) {
    let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;
  
    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
  
      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;
  
      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
   return array;
  }
  for (let i = 1; i <=8; i+=2) {
    randomNumbers.push(i);
    randomNumbers.push(i);
  }
  shuffle(randomNumbers);
  console.log(randomNumbers);
})();
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы подбили на правильную мысль, только там не
 for (let i = 1; i <=8; i+=2) {
    randomNumbers.push(i);
    randomNumbers.push(i);
  }
а 
for (let i = 1; i <=8; i++) {
    randomNumbers.push(i);
    randomNumbers.push(i);
  }

Comment: Проверьте сами)

Comment: может и так. просто я думал что вам нужно 8 чисел в общей сложности.. ну значит просто два push сделать

Comment: Видимо не совсем правильно выразился, нужны парные числа от 1 до 8, т.е. 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8
В любом случае, вы помогли решить задачу, спасибо

Comment: @Сергей push может принимать за раз множество элементов, нет необходимости его два раза вызывать.  randomNumbers.push(i, i);